# Is it possible to fetch data about when the app was last updated

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store

In my app, I want to show when it was last updated from AppStore. Is it possible? Thanks!

Something like this: [Android app get last date updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748708/android-app-get-last-date-updated)

It's for Android.

Comment: Maybe you can find something relevant in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256748/check-if-my-app-has-a-new-version-on-appstore)

Comment: Yes, but it may be more work than you want - or need - to do. The clear and definitive way is to look at the receipt. But you can probably go to simply hard-coding something inside your app. Wy not ask a more specific question, detailing what you need and what you've tried?

Comment: I can't add what I've tried because I cannot even find the examples to follow :)

Comment: Anyway, seems like there is no a simple way to fetch this data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108474/get-last-update-date-for-ios-application

 Andy Ibanez: "
iOS does not keep the last update time on its bundle like Android does. You will need to either write it manually to your plist with a run script phase or keep a server with the last update time which the app will check against.
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no a simple way to fetch this data: stackoverflow.com/questions/39108474/… Andy Ibanez: " iOS does not keep the last update time on its bundle like Android does. You will need to either write it manually to your plist with a run script phase or keep a server with the last update time which the app will check against. "